# Unable to detect wireless with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't detect any kind of wireless connection. However, when I plug in an Ethernet cable, it works perfectly. Windows 8, which is installed in dual boot with Ubuntu, connects with the wireless network perfectly.

I know this problem is pretty common, but I'm posting this here because I've read dozens of solutions but nothing has worked so far. I downloaded Synaptic, ndiswrapper and entered many commands in the Terminal, but nothing seems to fix the problem.

Comment: The response to # lspci | grep Network is: 01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
I downloaded a Realtek driver (RTL8188EE) for windows (.exe file), extracted it and then installed the .inf file with ndiswrapper, but it didn't make any change.

Answer (score 0):

You actually may need to install a wireless driver.

I'm running a new laptop myself and I had to get my dad to install a wireless driver and a graphics driver (seeing as I'm running Ubuntu and Windows 7 on a Windows 8 machine).

Look up what wireless driver you may need for your computer, and see if you can find a program which will set up the driver for you.